# aChartEngine very thin bar graph

Tags: android, achartengine

I'm working with aChartEngine. I populate my values from db, then add them into XY series. Everything goes perfect, except when there is only one bar in graph, it shows up as a very thin bar, but when there are more bars, they seem perfectly bold. Here is my code below:

```
XYSeriesRenderer xySeriesRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
xySeriesRenderer.setColor(Color.parseColor("#6ACEEB"));
xySeriesRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);
xySeriesRenderer.setChartValuesTextAlign(Align.CENTER);
xySeriesRenderer.setChartValuesTextSize(16f);

XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(xySeriesRenderer);
mRenderer.setAntialiasing(true);
mRenderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(false);
mRenderer.setShowLegend(false);
mRenderer.setShowLabels(true);
mRenderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
mRenderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
mRenderer.setChartTitle("Title");
mRenderer.setChartTitleTextSize(18f);
mRenderer.setXTitle("X Title");
mRenderer.setYTitle("Y Title");
mRenderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(18f);
mRenderer.setChartValuesTextSize(16f);
mRenderer.setLabelsTextSize(18f);
mRenderer.setLabelsColor(Color.BLACK);
mRenderer.setShowGridX(true);
mRenderer.setBarSpacing(0.01d);
mRenderer.setMarginsColor(Color.WHITE);
mRenderer.setGridColor(Color.DKGRAY);
mRenderer.setXLabelsColor(Color.DKGRAY);
mRenderer.setXAxisMin(0);
mRenderer.setYAxisMin(0);
mRenderer.setPanEnabled(true, false);
mRenderer.setAxesColor(Color.DKGRAY);
```

Also is it possible to set zoom value to a specific rate (such as %75 of graph) at first ?

Edit: I added two pictures, first one has multiple columns while second one has one column. I want second picture's bar as bold as first one.

http://s889.photobucket.com/user/gravis502/media/Screenshot_2013-11-13-17-04-36_zps468247ec.png.html

http://s889.photobucket.com/user/gravis502/media/Screenshot_2013-11-13-17-04-21_zpsab316ee2.png.html

Answer (score 0):

When there is only one item in the series, you can call the following method to control its width:

```
mRenderer.setBarWidth(width);
```

Comment: Thanks for your helped, solved out with a simple if block. I wonder is there a way to display graph as soon as draw scaled ? I want to show graph unzoomed at first.